# Infinite gas requirement in solidity

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, remix, decentralized-applications

I wrote a simple calculator program in solidity. I recieved error given as

*"Gas requirement of function calculator.add is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)"*

Can anyone point out where it went wrong? Thanks in advance

here's my code

```
`// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract calculator{
    int result;

    function add(int a,int b) public {
            result = a+b;
    }
     function sub(int a,int b) public {
            result = a-b;
    }
     function mul(int a,int b) public {
            result = a*b;
    }
     function div(int a,int b) public {
         require(b!=0,"B should not be 0!");
            result = a/b;
    }

    function getResult()public view returns (int) {
        return result;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a runtime error, EVM can't estimate the gas expense. You should look for runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

**check if your wallet network is equal to the network you deployed your contract !**

maybe you just send transaction with  **wrong selected network**  from your wallet

for example if you deploy your contract into **BSC** and your wallet selected network is **sepolia test-net** you receive  **can't estimate the gas expense**